# Why $document.referrer in angular js returning blank. But when i use document.referrer it is returning me value

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jqlite

```
var referrer = $document.referrer;
```

Need the value of

```
$document.referrer
```

in a variable.

Answer (score 3):

*$document* is actually a jqLite/jQuery query result soi the property doesn't exists. If you want to get the referrer you can:

a) Access the DOM document directly:

```
var referrer = document.referrer;
```

This is not recommended as you will fall in trouble writing unit tests.

b) Reference the object inside the jqLite/jQuery query result:

```
var referrer = $document[0].referrer;
```

Personally I do not like this approach either, the code becomes ugly and misleading.

c) Decorate *$document*:

```
myApp.config(function($provide){
  $provide.decorator('$document', function($delegate){

    $delegate.getReferrer = function() {return document.referrer;};

    // alternative you can create a property
    // Object.defineProperty($delegate, 'referrer', {  
    //   get: function() { return document.referrer; }
    // });

    return $delegate; 
  });
});
```

and then to get the referrer:

```
var referrer = $document.getReferrer();
//Or if you created a property...
//var referrer = $document.referrer;
```

I prefer this option because you can easily mock this object in unit tests and your code is easier to understand.

Comment: Or just reference it via `$window.document.referrer`, which is mockable for tests.